# VS2017 Setting up platform-specific packages

Tags: msbuild, nuget, visual-studio-2017

In previous versions of VS2017, we were able to use nuspec to specify platform specific dlls, e.g., Test.dll and Test.Net45.dll for Net45, and TEst.dll and Test.iOS.dll for iOS. VS2017 provides a Package tab which allows specifying versions, descriptions, etc. but there does not seem to be a way to specify platform. I do see Configuration: N/A and Platform: N/A but these are probably not relevant. How can this be done?

Incidentally, multi-targeting would not work, because Test.dll has to stay PCL (netstandard13).

We use msbuild pack in TeamCity.

Comment: .NET Standard projects should be supported by all platforms that implement the standard version. Thus, **you no longer need to specify which special platforms to target**. You should now keep this in mind, and forget about the legacy way.

Comment: @tofutim why does multi-targeting not work for you? netstandard is NOT a PCL. It was/is possible to modify a PCL project to target netstandard but it is rather quirky and replaced in vs 2017 by the new-style "sdk-based" csproj. This project types support e.g. `<TargetFrameworks>net45;netstandard1.3</…>`. If you can't do this, please be more specify about **why**.

Comment: It is because the main dll needs to be called by a netstandard13 library which is then called by the platform app project. If I use multi-targeting, and add the nuget package to both the netstandard13 library and the platform app project, won't one dll get overwritten by the platform one?

Comment: Perhaps I'm thinking about this wrong. I am using MvvmCross and I have a netstandard13 Core library which is then referenced by the platform library. I have a third library that provides utilities to the netstandard13 Core. This third library would ideally use multi-targeting.